# How to add additional field to django oscar product field in dashboard

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, django-oscar

How do I add an additional field to django-oscar dashboard? I've forked catalog app added an extra field, but the form is not showing after forking dashboard.

```
from django.db import models
from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProduct


class Product(AbstractProduct):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/%Y/%m/%d')


from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *
```

dashboard/catalogue/forms.py

```
from oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue import forms as base_forms


class ProductForm(base_forms.ProductForm):

    class Meta(base_forms.ProductForm.Meta):

        fields = ('file',)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, create a directory to hold the forked app
example forked_app_dir
next use `oscar_fork_app` utility (which is very very poorly documented when you want to fork the dashboard apps)
in my case, I wanted to fork the catalogue dashboard app so I did `./manage.py oscar_fork_app` dashboard then changed into the dashboard directory and did `./manage.py oscar_fork_app catalogue_dashboard` which created another dashboard dir which I removed and everything worked fine after applying changes forms in the dashboard.

Comment: I haven't found the way to fork sub_app anywhere on the doc : oscar_fork_app catalogue_dashboard. Thanks for that !

Comment: The way you have written is not more beneficial than doc. Can you plz elaborate the steps?

Comment: This Works! Been searching for a way to achieve this.